# ERROR in ./~/sockjs-client/~/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket/client.js calling webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am getting the following error calling webpack-dev-server:

```
ERROR in ./~/sockjs-client/~/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket/client.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/Users/lololo/src/lalala/node_modules/sockjs-client/node_modules/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket'
 @ ./~/sockjs-client/~/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket/client.js 2:13-27
 @ ./~/sockjs-client/~/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket.js
 @ ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/driver/websocket.js
 @ ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/websocket.js
 @ ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport-list.js
 @ ./~/sockjs-client/lib/entry.js
 @ (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js
 @ (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
 @ multi main
```

My package.json looks like:

`{
  "name": "editor",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "backbone": "^1.3.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "highlight.js": "^9.6.0",
    "marked": "^0.3.6",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "nuka-carousel": "^2.0.2",
    "react": "^15.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.1.6",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "store": "^1.3.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^15.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.0.14",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.0",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.24.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.4.1",
    "eslint": "^3.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^4.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "jest": "^15.1.1",
    "jest-cli": "^16.0.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "lodash": "^4.15.0",
    "ncp": "^2.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.3.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.3.2",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "selenium-standalone": "^5.1.0",
    "sinon": "^1.17.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webdriverio": "^4.0.9",
    "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.22",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.1.0-beta.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --no-cache",
    "lint": "eslint app/es6",
    "clean-distx": "rimraf dist && mkdir dist",
    "wp": "webpack --env.dev -p",
    "build": "jest && npm run clean-dist && webpack --env.prod -p  && npm run copy-files",
    "copy-files": "babel-node --presets es2017 tools/copy.js",
    "purgeDist": "rm dist/*.pem",
    "deploy": "npm run purgeDist && firebase deploy",
    "server": "webpack-dev-server --env.dev --content-base dist",
    "start": "npm run clean-dist && npm run copy-files && npm run server"
  },
  "jest": {
    "automock": true,
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "react",
      "react-dom",
      "react-addons-test-utils",
      "fbjs",
      "enzyme",
      "cheerio",
      "htmlparser2",
      "underscore",
      "lodash",
      "domhandler",
      "object.assign",
      "define-properties",
      "function-bind",
      "object-keys",
      "moment",
      "store"
    ],
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "integrationTests"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "models/(.*)": "<rootDir>/app/es6/models/$1",
      "controllers/(.*)": "<rootDir>/app/es6/controllers/$1",
      "components/(.*)": "<rootDir>/app/es6/components/$1",
      "stores/(.*)": "<rootDir>/app/es6/stores/$1",
      "reducers/(.*)": "<rootDir>/app/es6/reducers/$1"
    }
  }
}`

and webpack config is:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const jsConfig = env => ({
    target: 'web',
    context: __dirname + '/app',
    entry: './es6/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    // Important! Do not remove ''. If you do, imports without
    // an extension won't work anymore!
    resolve: {
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'), 'node_modules'],
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
        aliasFields: ['components'],
        alias: {
            es6: 'es6',
            components: 'es6/components',
            controllers: 'es6/controllers',
            models: 'es6/models',
            stores: 'es6/stores',
            reducers: 'es6/reducers'
        },
    },
    devtool: env.prod ? false : 'eval',
    // externals: [
    //     'sockjs'
    //
    // ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json'},
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel', // 'babel-loader' is also a legal name to reference
                query: {
                    presets: [['es2015', {'modules': false}], 'react', 'stage-0']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './app',
        inline: true,
        hot: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\\\/]locale$/, /^\.\/(en)$/),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            React: 'react',
            ReactDOM: 'react-dom'

        })
    ]
});

const cssConfig = env => ({
    context: __dirname + '/app',
    entry: './sass/main.scss',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.css',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/styles')
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.s?css/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: 'css!sass' })
            },
            { test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]' },
            { test: /\.woff$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]' },
            { test: /\.woff2$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff2&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]' },
            { test: /\.[ot]tf$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]' },
            { test: /\.eot$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/vnd.ms-fontobject&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]' }

        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('main.css')
    ]
});

module.exports = env => [jsConfig(env), cssConfig(env)];
```

I haven't yet found any references online of anyone having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found my 'alias' and 'aliasFields' were causing this issue on webpack 2.

I have removed the 'aliasFields' completely and replaced 'alias' with the following:

`alias: {
        es6: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/es6'),
        components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/es6/components'),
        controllers: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/es6/controllers'),
        models: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/es6/models'),
        stores: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/es6/stores'),
        reducers: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/es6/reducers')
    },`

which seems to do the trick.

However, I'm still not sure where to find the complete webpack 2 documentation on those fields. And I also know I'm not using neither the best approach to deal with those folders, nor the best folder structure for a React-Redux project.